How do I add hours if my string is "6/27/2024 12:27:00 AM" in Java?
I need to add 8 hours on the hours of "6/27/2024 12:27:00 AM", so the result should be  "6/27/2024 8:27:00 PM" and return it as String.
I tried using regex but is flawed and too complicated, got to add if condition for AM and PM changing. I'm looking for the simplest way to go about this.

Convert to LocalDate (plenty of questions on stackoverflow on how to do that), add the 8 hours (with the plus method), convert back to string (plenty of questions as well).

Do you want to do this in Java code and then update the webpage? Or do you want to directly manipulate the webpage using selenium?

"got to add if condition for AM and PM changing", not just that, adding 8 hours could change the day of the month, which could in turn change both the month and the year (i.e. on 31/12/2024, it can become 1/1/2025). Use java.time.LocalDate as was suggested

"6/27/2024 12:27:00 AM" is wrong. No such time exists DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/uuuu HH:mm:ss a", Locale.US);LocalDateTime eightHoursLater = LocalDateTime.parse("6/27/2024 12:27:00 PM", dtf).plusHours(8); Not LocalDate btw

Then LocalDateTime.parse(s, dtf).plusHours(8).format(dtf); gives you 6/27/2024 20:27:00 PM

BTW do not use LocalDate as suggested (and upvoted??), use LocalDateTime since you need the time part too

Thank you g00se and QBrute for bringing to my attention that Calendar is outdated:
String input = "6/27/2024 12:27:00 AM";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);

try {
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(input, formatter);

    // Add hours
    LocalDateTime newDateTime = dateTime.plusHours(3);
    String formattedDateTime = newDateTime.format(formatter);

    System.out.println("Original date time: " + input);
    System.out.println("Date time after adding hours: " + formattedDateTime);
} catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
    System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
}

Result
Original date time: 6/27/2024 12:27:00 AM
Date time after adding hours: 6/27/2024 3:27:00 AM


I see that 12:27:00 AM is actually ok for a 12 hour clock, but I'm surprised you got away with AM for an English locale as it's actually am in the UK

Ah right - thanks! In that case, it might make am/pm effectively case-insensitive I guess... Wait - it doesn't. am (the correct form for the UK) throws an exception ;)
